# Как вывести цену акций и даты на график Highcharts

Tags: javascript, api, highcharts

Всем привет. Мне нужно создать график, показывающий динамику цены акций, на основе данных, полученных из API. Для отрисовки графика использую Highcharts. Не получается вывести данные на график в нужной последовательности. График или не видит даты или подставляют дату на место цены.
[image: дата подставилась вместо цены]

В [тестовой ссылке Highcharts](https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json) данные для отрисовки приходят в виде массива, содержащего дату в виде количества миллисекунд прошедших с 01.01.1970, и цену. Я привел данные, полученные от API к такому же формату и тоже поместил их в массив, но когда пытаюсь скормить эти данные графику он воспринимает их неправильно. Хочу понять что я делаю не так. В текущий момент данные, которые передаю я, выглядят так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объект графика:

```js
const chartCompany = Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
        chart: {
          width: 1050,
          height: 400
        },
    
        title: {
          
        },
    
        subtitle: {
          
        },
    
        rangeSelector: {
          selected: 0
        },
    
        series: [{
          name: AAPL Stock Price`,
          data: histPriceData,
          type: 'area',
          threshold: null,
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
          }
        }],
    
        responsive: {
          rules: [{
            condition: {
              maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
              chart: {
                height: 300
              },
              subtitle: {
                text: null
              },
              navigator: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      });
```

Наполнение массива данными:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < historicalPrices.length; i++){
        
        histPriceData.push(new Date(historicalPrices[i].date).getTime());
        histPriceData.push(historicalPrices[i].close);
      }
```

При наполнении массива я перевожу данные из формата UTC (в котором они приходят от API) в количество миллисекунд, прошедших с 01.01.1970. Пробовал разбивать данные на 2 массива и передать оба в data графика, пробовал передавать данные в data без массива и пробовал передавать их в data как массив в массиве. Ничего не помогает. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Всем спасибо за внимание. При наполнении массива нужно было вместо метода push использовать unshift